# How to get the variable for which a property is defined in coderush?

Tags: coderush

```
private int _i;

public int  Count
{
    get {  return _i;  }
}
```

How to get the `variable _i` when we have the property "Count" using CodeRush APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code, hopefully it will be of some help:

```
Variable GetPropertyVariable(Property property)
{
  if (property == null)
    return null;

  Get getter = property.Getter;
  if (getter == null)
    return null;

  Return returnStatement = getter.FindChildByElementType(LanguageElementType.Return) as Return;
  if (returnStatement == null)
    return null;

  Expression returnExpression = returnStatement.Expression;
  ElementReferenceExpression targetExpression = returnExpression as ElementReferenceExpression;
  if (targetExpression == null)
    targetExpression = returnExpression.FindChildByElementType(LanguageElementType.ElementReferenceExpression) as ElementReferenceExpression;
  if (targetExpression == null)
    return null;

  return targetExpression.GetDeclaration(true) as Variable;
}
```

Comment: thank you Alex....This code is returning null for the dependency property in your console application...Can you please help me in this regard.
**CODE FOR THE PROPERTY:**

public static readonly DependencyProperty HeightProperty     = DependencyProperty.Register("Height", typeof(int), typeof(A),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0,
        FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits));

    public int Height
    {
        get
        {
            return (int)GetValue(HeightProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(HeightProperty, value);
        }
    }

Comment: I've modified the code in my answer and I hope it will work for dependency properties as well. The main idea is to locate a reference element of the ElementReferenceExpression type and then get the referenced declaration by calling the GetDeclaration method.

Comment: Thank you Alex. This works well with dependency properties also.